# Como almacenar un checkbox en un vector en Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Debo almacenar en un vector el nombre seleccionado en el check, solo se debe mostrar: {{seleccion.nombre}} y que debo poner en el ts?.

```
       <tr *ngFor=" let seleccion of selecciones"> 
            <td>

                <input type="checkbox" name="Activo" ng-model="Activo">                       
                {{seleccion.nombre}} 

            </td>               
            <td>{{seleccion.entidad}}</td>
            <div id="Logo">
                <img style="width:90px; height:90px;" src="{{ seleccion.imagen}}" />                                
            </div>
       </tr>
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo aca le dejo una respuesta bien simple.

html

```
<tr *ngFor=" let seleccion of selecciones"> 
    <td>

        <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="seleccion.selected" (change)="checkValue(seleccion)">                     
        {{seleccion.nombre}} 

    </td>               
    <td>{{seleccion.entidad}}</td>
    <div id="Logo">
        <img style="width:90px; height:90px;" src="{{ seleccion.imagen}}" />                                
    </div>
</tr>
```

typescript en el componente:

```
...
selecciones = [
    { name: 'JS',  selected: true, id: 12, entidad: 'Endidad1', image: 'image.jpg' },
    { name: 'CSS', selected: false, id: 2, entidad: 'Endidad2', image: 'image.jpg'},
  ];

  checkValue(seleccion: any){
    this.selecciones.find( x => x.id == event.id).selected = seleccion.selected;
    console.log(this.selecciones);
 }
...
```

Espero esto le ayude a resolver su problema